# Native Policy Intersection in ESB

Tags: esb, intersection, wso2, policy, wso2-esb

I try to find a ESB which supports a intersection of policies from the request (client) and the available webservices (providers).

The ideal configuration would include a Service-Registry where a query could be sent to from the ESB. The ESB could verify the functional an non-functional (policy) requirements.

I tried to create a setup with products of WSO2 but failed, because there is no generic policy-intersection module. When I had a look at some other vendors I realized that I only find specific use of WS-Policy like SecurityPolicy, RM  ... . But I didn't find a generic policy intersection module which could check the domain independent compatibility between requester and provider (like proposed here: http://wiki.apache.org/general/ManojPushpakumara/GSoC/proposal).

Are there any ESB available (OpenSource preferred) which support something like this? If not how to integrate such a functionality for example into the WSO2 ESB?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a very difficult requirement. I am not sure whether it is possible to derive the policy from the xml. since it may not be one to one.

Normal technique we use here is to use different bindings with different policies and ask user to send the message to the correct binding.

Comment: What do you mean by deriving the polic from xml. The request could contain a policy as well as a service could provide a policy. So if there are 3 Services available I what to select the one how is compatible with the policy inside the request. I recognized that the in the WSO2 Products (like ESB) I could set a Policy of a Service. Whats the sense of this policy if I couldn't use it for defining the non-functional requirements?

Comment: The idea of that policy is it is the way that service going to process the message. so user need to send the request according to the policy.

Comment: So ideally I want to do this whole process automatic, as described by the WS-Policy Standard. I have managed to get the service policy and now have to intersect it with the client policy, but recognized that wso2esb uses neethi 2.0.4 which doesn't have intersection functionalities. How can I use the newer neethi 3.0.2, if necessary only for a class mediator I wrote (posted this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845135/do-policy-intersection-in-wso2esb-class-mediator)