# Do Policy Intersection in WSO2ESB Class Mediator

Tags: wso2, intersection, policy, wso2-esb

I've created a Class Mediator in which I want to intersect two policies. I've created the Class Mediator with Carbon Studio for Eclipse, which automatically adds some predefined libs to the build path of my project.

One of the libs is neethi-2.0.4.wso2v1.jar.

If I want to use the intersect-method I get an exception. If I have a look at the source I see that the intersect-method just throws an "UnsupportedOperationException".

So the given neethi lib is useless for intersection, therefore I want to use the newest Neethi lib (aka neethi-3.0.2.lib) for intersection inside my class mediator.

Could you tell me how I can include third party libs, especially in my use case these ones, that should override the once used inside the esb( neethi-2.0.4.wso2v1.jar).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Developer Studio adds these libs to your project classpath, so that developers do not get build errors in the source code.

Therefore those libraries are only for the development time and available only with Dev Studio. They are not the libraries used in the runtime of the server.

Runtime libraries are provided by the WSO2 Carbon Server runtime. So this UnsupportedOperationException is thrown by the server is occurred due to the version of the neethi in the server does not support it. So you need to upgrade the library in the server runtime.

But as you can see, WSO2 have forked the neethi codebase and have some custom implementations on the forked source. So IMO, simply upgrading the version would not help.

Anyway you need to actually upgrade the library and see whether you face any issues with it.

To upgrade the versions, you can either create a Java Library artifact for newer Neethi library and include it in the CAR file and deploy the CAR file or copy the new Neethi library to `<CARBON_HOME>/repository/components/lib` location while the server is running.

You can find the current Neethi library in the `<CARBON_HOME>/repository/components/plugins` location. If you find some error or exception similar to "Linkage Error", then try to remove the older version of the library. But it would cause some other exceptions.

So IMO the bottom line is, you will face some issues with the version upgrade. But yes of course you can give a try and see, whether we can overcome them. Give it a try and post your observations here. We will try our best to assist you.

Comment: Hi,  I was aware that the libs in carbon studio are only added for the development time, and therefore tried to add the Neethi-3.0.2 lib to the ESB.  I will explain the steps I've made in more detail  First of all, Neethi-2.0.4.wso2v3 does not only support intersection but also normalization of policies (see http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/carbon-dev/2011-August/066825.html ).

Comment: So If try to run my Class Mediator with original neethi-2.0.4.wso2v3.jar using only a normalize (not an intersect method) I get: NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.neethi.Policy.normalize(Z)Lorg/apache/neethi/Policy;.     I then added the Neethi-3.0.2.jar to <esb_home>/repository/components/jar, restarted the ESB and run the example again. Now normalization works, I do not get any errors.

Comment: Next I started to extend my Class Mediator with intersection-functionality. Therefore I created a PolicyBuilder and PolicyRegistry, which are needed for intersection in Neethi-3.0.2 (see neethi tests for that). static PolicyBuilder policyEngine = new PolicyBuilder();
 static PolicyRegistry registry = new PolicyRegistryImpl(); and in my method: policyEngine.setPolicyRegistry(registry); and Policy intersectedPolicy = (Policy) policy1.intersect(policy2);

Comment: Then I get an Exception for the line: static PolicyBuilder policyEngline = new PolicyBuilder(); which says: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/neethi/PolicyBuilder at iaas.unistuttgart.de.utils.Discovery.DiscoveryUtils.(DiscoveryUtils.java:42) "

Comment: So somehow the new Neethi lib is used (which can be seen because normalization works). On the other hand it does not work completely, because no PulicyBuilder class can be found (and therefore intersection cannot be used). I think this is because the two neethi version jars have the same naming and maybe PolicyBuilder could not be found, because there is no PolicyBuilder-Class in neethi-2.0.4...?

Comment: Could you please provide me with help maybe with respect to (http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/carbon-dev/2011-August/066825.html) someone of you already has done something similar? If not is there any workaround of fix if I could use neethi 3.0.2, maybe only inside my mediator, and not for the rest of the esb as a whole?

Comment: Actually,I have not done this before nor heard anyone did try it before. But following is an option. Neethi is exposed as an OSGi bundle with version 2.0.4.wso2v3. So if you can convert the neethi 3.0.2 to an OSGi bundle using Maven bundle plugin. Then you can have both neethi 2.0.4.wso2v3 and neethi 3.0.2 in the same OSGi environment since the versions are different. Class mediator is also an OSGi bundle and in the class mediator, you can explicitly set the import package neethi version to 3.0.2. With this mechanism, you will be able to overcome the issue.

Comment: I thougt that if I copy a .jar to <esb_home>/library/components/lib, the jar gets automatically converted into and OSGI-bundle (says article http://wso2.org/library/knowledgebase/add-external-jar-libraries-wso2-carbon-based-products). Can I see all loaded OSGI-Bundles, with their corresponding versions, in the Management-UI-Console of WSO2 ESB? Concerning the class mediator. I tought you told me that changes I make in eclipse doesn't matter because the esb uses its own libs? If now, how can I an explicit version of neethi in class mediator?

Comment: Another problem with the solution would be, that If I want to migrate my code from a mediator to an custom endpoint, I think your solution wouldn't work. Best way for me however would be to completely exchange neethi 2.0.4 inside the esb with neethi 3.0.2. Is there any way to do this

Comment: I could check the active OSGI-bundles with parameter -DosgiConsole. I see that both Neethi libs are loaded and active, however my noClassDefinitionFound Error still exists. I wasn't able to build Neethi 3.0.2 as an OSGI bundle by myself, but I think bundle which gets auto-generated, when I put neethi in /libs folder, does well for that (it has a version 1.0.0, which is different from wso2s 2.0.4wso2v3). You write that I can explicitly set the import package of neethi to a specific version? Could you tell me how I could do this in carbon studio?